# Python Mechanize to check if a server is available

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize

I'm trying to write a script which will read a file containing some urls and then open   a browser instance using mechanize module. I'm just wondering how I can do so if some url does not exist or if the server is unreachable.

For Example

```
import mechanize  

br = mechanize.Browser()  
b  = br.open('http://192.168.1.30/index.php')
```

What I want to know is how I will get information from mechanize if 192.168.1.30 is unreachable or if http returns 404 Error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from mechanize import Browser
browser = Browser()
response = browser.open('http://www.google.com')
print response.code
```

Or Use Python requests library.

Sample code demonstrating it:

```
>>>import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Comment: if the response is 404 this will throw you an error before it gets to print anything so without exception handling it is close to useless.

Comment: @root I'm just showing him the concept of getting status code. He can do the exception handling himself.

Comment: @ Sibi -- in case of 404, response never gets defined, so even if you handle the exception respone.code will get you a nameerror.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
from mechanize import Browser
b = Browser()
try:
    r=b.open('http://www.google.com/foobar')
except (mechanize.HTTPError,mechanize.URLError) as e:
    if isinstance(e,mechanize.HTTPError):
        print e.code
    else:
        print e.reason.args
```

Output:

```
404
```

If you  try `'http://www.google.foo'` it will get you a tuple:

`(-2, 'Name or service not known')`