# How to make a script wait within an iteration until the Internet connection is reestablished?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, mechanize

I have a scraping code within a `for` loop, but it would take several hours to complete, and the program stops when my Internet connection breaks. What I (think I) need is a condition at the beginning of the scraper that tells Python to keep trying at that point.
I tried to use the answer from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613733/handling-exceptions-from-urllib2-and-mechanize-in-python):

```
for w in wordlist:

#some text processing, works fine, returns 'textresult'

    if textresult == '___':  #if there's nothing in the offline resources
        bufferlist = list()
        str1=str()
        mlist=list()  # I use these in scraping

        br = mechanize.Browser()

        tried=0
        while True:
            try:
                br.open("http://the_site_to_scrape/")

                # scraping, with several ifs. Each 'for w' iteration results with scrape_result string.


            except (mechanize.HTTPError, mechanize.URLError) as e:
                tried += 1
                if isinstance(e,mechanize.HTTPError):
                    print e.code
                else:
                    print e.reason.args
            if tried > 4:
                    exit()
                    time.sleep(120)
                    continue
            break
```

Works while I'm online. When the connection breaks, Python writes the 403 code and skips that word from `wordlist`, moves on to the next and does the same. How can I tell Python to wait for connection within the iteration?

**EDIT**: I would appreciate it if you could write at least some of the necessary commands and tell me where they should be placed in my code, because I've never dealt with exception loops.

**EDIT - SOLUTION** I applied Abhishek Jebaraj's modified solution. I just added a very simple exception handling command:

```
except:
    print "connection interrupted"
    time.sleep(30)
```

Also, Jebaraj's getcode command will raise an error. Before r.getcode, I used this:

```
import urllib

r = urllib.urlopen("http: the site ")
```

The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758029/try-block-inside-while-statement) helped me as well.

Comment: Check for `status/10!=20`, and keep retrying the loop. Just put everything inside the for loop in a `while(retry)` loop, and modify the value of retry to `False` for status 2xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write another while loop inside which will keep trying to connect to the internet.

It will break only when it receives status code of 200 and then you can continue with your program.

Kind of like

```
retry = True
while retry:
    try:
        r = br.open(//your site)
        if r.getcode()/10==20:
            retry = False
    except:
          // code to handle any exception

// rest of your code
```

Comment: That goes inside the `while True:` I have written in my question?
And //code to handle any exception can be the same as in my question?

Comment: Yes it goes inside the while loop in your question and the //code to handle is whatever you want.. maybe you want to break it during successive connection errors.. or you could just pass its up to you..

Comment: Same logic in my latest edit, just made it a bit more shorter.. based on ishaans answer in the comments..

Comment: I had an error `closeable_response instance has no attribute 'getcode'`. Solved it, but now I still get an error when I go offline: `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed `. Also, when I went offline, the word Python was working on was discarded -- I got `(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine')` and saw Python went on to the next word.